# How can I make my CSS move as the user types?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basic email signature for myself but I need it move as I type the email. Currently I have the positions fixed, however the contents of the div tag stay in place so the contents of the email overlap. How can I make it so that the signature moves but keeps its positions?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span style="color: rgb(86, 106, 17);">My Name<br>
Technical Support and Sales</span></br>
<span style="color: rgb(86, 106, 17);">A Phone Number
x 22</span>
<span style="color: rgb(86, 106, 17);"><br>
<a href="http://website.com">
Website.com</a> - Phrase<br>
</span></i></span>
<div style="position: relative; left: 7px; top: 140px;">
<div style="position: fixed; left: 7px; top: 140px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img
src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
alt=""></a></div> 

<div style="position: fixed; left: 35px; top: 142px;">Add Us on Facebook </div><br>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 7px; top: 170px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img
src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
alt=""></a></div>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 35px; top: 154px;"><p>Follow Us on Twitter</p></div>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 7px; top: 185px;"><i><p>P.S. Bogged down with routine tasks?
Book a FREE workshop to see how we can help streamline your day-to-day activities and save time.
Click here to schedule your one-on-one workshop at a time that's convenient for you. </p>       </i></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `position: fixed`. Also, doing what you're trying to do for an email signature won't work for most email clients in the market.

Comment: Also, if I were you, I would use tables rather than divs for emails. While the support of divs now has more reach in mail clients, it still is not a bullet proof way of creating html-email, and it will have problems displaying in older mail clients. 

Tables are more work, but if they are well styled and nested, it will look the same in every mail client you can think of, because of their suffocating nature.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed all the fixed to absolute and then created a div with a relative position to contain it all. Now as the user types the signature moves with it but keeps the style I created.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 5px;">
<span style="color: rgb(86, 106, 17);">Your name<br>
Technical Support and Sales</span></br>
<span style="color: rgb(86, 106, 17);">A Phone number
x 22</span>
<span style="color: rgb(86, 106, 17);"><br>
<a href="http://website.com">
website.com</a> - phrase
</span></i></span></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 105px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img
src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
alt=""></a></div> 

<div style="position: absolute; left: 35px; top: 106px;">Add Us on Facebook </div><br>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 135px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img
src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
alt=""></a></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 35px; top: 119px;"><p>Follow Us on Twitter</p></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 151px;"><i><p>P.S. Bogged down with routine tasks?
Book a FREE workshop to see how we can help streamline your day-to-day activities and save time.
Click here to schedule your one-on-one workshop at a time that's convenient for you. </p></i></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

to manipulate css in real time as the user types, you need to use JavaScript.
a good simple library for javascript is jQuery. which is basically ajvascript simplified.

what you need is this method:
http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

good luck

Comment: You can't execute JavaScript in emails (all clients I know of strips it out).

Comment: you will never be able to modify content of email you sent someone, on the fly while they read it. thats just not the way email works. :(

Comment: @Kirka121 I'm not trying to allow the receiver of the email to modify it. When the sender clicks compose and the signature appears, you should be able to type the message and the signature should moved down accordingly.

Comment: <div id="text"><input type="text" /></div><div id="signature"><img href="signature"/></div> and type the text in the top input. whats the problem.

Comment: add <textarea> instead of input if you want a bigger comment box

Comment: @Kirka121 The px positions you see in the code need to remain the same. It was styled a certain way. The issue is keeping my style and allowing movement.

Comment: on the #signature{padding-top:20px;}